# Pushing footer under white background div

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I have a div called content with a background color of white. I'm having an issue where I got the footer to stay at the bottom of the page, but it's on top of the content div. See pic as reference. I want it to always be under the content div, but also always at the bottom of the page if it zooms out. 
A perfect example of what I want is http://www.jquery.com 's footer style

Here's a demo http://www.andrewhnovak.com/test/index.html
[image]

HTML

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">

        <title>Site Demo</title>
        <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <link href="css/header.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <link href="css/mainPage.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

    <script type="text/javascript">
    function setnewcontentheight(){     
        $("#inhalt").height(Math.max($(window).height()-$("#footer").height(),$('#inhalt').height()));      
    }

    $(window).resize(function(){
        setnewcontentheight();
    });

    $(document).ready(function() {
        setnewcontentheight();
    }); 
    </script>

    </head>
```

CSS

```
 .footer { 
  z-index: 0;
  bottom: 0px;
  height: 40px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color:red;
}


.whiteBox{
    background-color:white;
    width:800px;
    height:800px;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    position:relative;
    top:80px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 10px 11px 5px -6px rgba(0,0,0,0.43);
-moz-box-shadow: 10px 11px 5px -6px rgba(0,0,0,0.43);
box-shadow: 10px 11px 5px -6px rgba(0,0,0,0.43);
margin-bottom:100px;
 z-index: 10;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside the setnewcontentheight function, do something like this:

```
$("div.container:nth-child(5)").height(innerHeight - 40 - $("#footer").height());
```

(It's a bit weird with the nth-child, you might want to create an ID or an easier selector to the container with the white sheet.)

Comment: Looked at your site again, do you have some elements with `position:absolute` within the container? That won't work...

Comment: This was absolute, but that's it                                                                                      * html #footer{
    position:absolute;
        top:expression((0-(footer.offsetHeight)+(document.documentElement.clientHeight ? document.documentElement.clientHeight : document.body.clientHeight)+(ignoreMe = document.documentElement.scrollTop ? document.documentElement.scrollTop : document.body.scrollTop))+'px');
}